# Does Heroku free tier support a video chat app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, webrtc

I have deployed my webrtc p2p video chat app. But for some reason the peer videos don't play for the devices that are not connected to the same network. I'm wondering if this has got anything to do with heroku. I have read in another thread that heroku free tier might not be allowing video streaming.

Comment: Peer-to-peer means Heroku isn't involved in that part. It's not Heroku, it's the nature of peer-to-peer, and it's the reason any major app that's using P2P also has a backup central server method as a fallback.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Heroku allows you to use WebRTC or any video chat method as long as it complies with their [Acceptable Use Policy](https://www.heroku.com/policy/aup). That being said, WebRTC works on Heroku.

This issue sounds like you are not connecting the candidates using signaling, like a STUN ice server.